# Error while Using H264VideoStreamSettings in flash

Tags: flash, h.264

I am newbie flash

I tried to encode camera stream with H.264, 
I found flash provides flash.media.H264VideoStreamSettings class.
I used this class

but i got following error:

```
typecheck cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline/netStatus()
outer-scope = [global Object$ flash.events::EventDispatcher$ flash.display::DisplayObject$ flash.display::InteractiveObject$ flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer$ flash.display::Sprite$ flash.display::MovieClip$ cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline$]

[cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O] flash.events::NetStatusEvent[O] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} ()  0:debugfile "cameraLiveStream_fla.MainTimeline::frame1"

[cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O] flash.events::NetStatusEvent[O] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} ()  2:debugline 22

[cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O] flash.events::NetStatusEvent[O] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} ()  4:getlocal0

[cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O] flash.events::NetStatusEvent[O] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {} (cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O])  5:pushscope

[cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O] flash.events::NetStatusEvent[O] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O]} ()  6:pushundefined

[cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O] flash.events::NetStatusEvent[O] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O]} (void[A])  7:coerce_a

[cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O] flash.events::NetStatusEvent[O] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O]} (*[A])  8:setlocal2

[cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O] flash.events::NetStatusEvent[O] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O]} ()  9:pushnull

[cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O] flash.events::NetStatusEvent[O] *[A] *[A] *[A]] {cameraLiveStream_fla::MainTimeline~[O]} (null[O]) 10:coerce


flash.media::H264VideoStreamSettings VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.media::H264VideoStreamSettings could not be found.
```

please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

1st sorry my poor english.
i had the same error in adobe flash pro cs4.
I solve my problem following this thread.
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/938568
I  download the PlayerGlobal (11.7) from adobe and set the library path in flashcs4.
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html